Connection refused when connecting via domain, but works fine via server ip on nginx serving a react build site
The issue is that I am hosting a react build site via nginx, on port 80 , when i try to connect to it via tha server ip of the vps, it directly connects and works like a charm, but when i try to connect to it via tha domain, it shows connection refused on the browser. and no error in the nginx logs.
Now the thing it , the domain also used to work like a charm, till i tried to shift it to 443 and get a certificate via certbot. In this the domain used to connect but my react site used to be stuck and not working, so i reverted it back by purging nginx and reinstalling it. Which I think is the issue but i've looked into everything and cannot seem to find the problem.
My DNS is set via cloudflare and is not proxied. If i enable cloudlfares proxy it connects to the site but the react app doesnt load, only the title of the entire page loads.
Cloudflare DNS Pic
Here is the nginx site conf.
also the curl output of curl http://xyz.xyz.xyz; //redacted to post online
does show me the actual html content, but cannot connect to it via browser
curl xyz.xyz.xyz; //redacted to post online
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><title>Weather Data</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.3a8a71db.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.59a99e0c.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="root"></div><script src="/src/index.js"></script></body></html>

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xyz.xyz.xyz; //redacted to post online
    root /root/arduino-data/weather-web-ui/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}

Here is the ufw status
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
3000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)


sudo netstat -plnt output

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16522/sshd: root@pt
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29627/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      740/mongod
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.54:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      649/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      649/systemd-resolve
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1015/node /root/ard
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      16522/sshd: root@pt
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/init


Let me know if there is anything else I can provide you with, Kinda new to using nginx.
Tried connecting via IP, works!, Via Domain , Connection Refused :(
Edit: Fixed?
All of this was because once i had tried the ssl, my browser automatically tried to connect to it via https instead of http no matter what I did. So I had to go in chrome://net-internals/#hsts and delete the stuff for my domain and also add it in the "Allow Insecure Content" list from chrome://settings/content/insecureContent Which seems to have fixed this issue.
However when using SSL I can't seem to understand why ther react app stops working/
